# Database throws Unable to Close Resource exception daily on first request

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I get the following exception for the first request that comes to my server every day: `org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToCloseResourceException: Unable to close Connection`. After the first request, any subsequent requests can access the database without any trouble until the next day. I am using jdbi and mysql db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a `ValidationQuery` which could be `SELECT 1`